# Get first (or any) value from HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    private List<Node> dirtyNodes = new List<Node> dirtyNodes();

    public void UpdateDirtyNodes()
    {
        while(dirtyNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            Node nodeToUpdate = dirtyNodes[0];
            nodeToUpdate.UpdateNode();
            dirtyNodes.Remove(nodeToUpdate);
        }
    }

    public void MarkNodeDirty(Node node)
    {
        if(!dirtyNodes.Contains(node))
        {
            dirtyNodes.Add(node);
        }
    }

    public void MarkNodeClean(Node node)
    {
        dirtyNodes.Remove(node);
    }
```

This is a performance-critical part of the code, and it's slower than I'd like because `dirtyNodes.Contains` has to iterate over the entire array in most cases. I'd like to replace the `List` with a `HashSet` because it should be faster, but I can't figure out how to make that work with `UpdateDirtyNodes()`.

The difficulty is that `UpdateNode()` can add or remove nodes from `dirtyNodes` at any time, hence the slightly awkward while loop. Is there a way I can get the "first" value from a HashSet? Order doesn't matter, I just need to stay in the while loop until `dirtyNodes` is empty, updating whatever node comes next.

I would prefer to avoid using Linq since this code will be part of a library and I don't want to force them to include Linq.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Progman No, I'm using C#.

Comment: Does `dirtyNodes.First()` not do what you want?

Comment: @41686d6564 I've updated the question. I don't want to use Linq because it'll be part of a library and I don't want to force people to include Linq. Or maybe I'm being paranoid and Linq is fine, idk.

Comment: System.Linq is a Microsoft supplied piece of the Framework. It's available wherever good C# code is used

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes but it seems like a very large library to include for one tiny piece of code.

Comment: @Clonkex How do you define "very large" and how did you measure it? Are you talking about the size of the System.Core.dll assembly? And how are you planning to _not_ include it? Please add that information to the question because right now it's unclear

Comment: `HashSet<T>` implemets `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can just iterate over it: `foreach (var node in dirtyNodes) { node.UpdateNode(); }`

Comment: @41686d6564 That's a very valid question. To be honest, I don't know to any of those questions. I've spent most of my time in recent years working in Javascript land, where the first response to any problem is "include a giant library", and while that's fine for most things, for performance-critical stuff it can be a really bad solution. I guess I see "using" as "including", which I assume isn't the case. Either way I've got a solution that I'm happy with; I'm just writing my answer now.

Comment: @KlausGütter Please re-read the question. I can't iterate over it because `UpdateNode` can modify the list I'm iterating over.

Comment: @Clondex Then you might coy the hash set to a list and iterator over the list: `var dirtyList = new List<T>(dirtyNodes);`

Comment: @KlausGütter How would that solve my problem? That would be so much worse. Instead of switching to a `HashSet` to remove the need for `List.Contains`, I add a second list, copy all the data across and then _still_ have to do `List.Contains`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's very easy to just use the enumerator directly:

```
    public void UpdateDirtyNodes()
    {
        while(dirtyNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            using(HashSet<Node>.Enumerator enumerator = dirtyNodes.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if(enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    Node nodeToUpdate = enumerator.Current;
                    nodeToUpdate.UpdateNode();
                    dirtyNodes.Remove(nodeToUpdate);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void MarkNodeDirty(Node node)
    {
        dirtyNodes.Add(node);
    }
```

I originally tried something similar but didn't fully understand how to manually use enumerators and it didn't work.

It's significantly faster than the `List` (overall frame time is ~25-50% faster depending on the situation just from that one change) so I'm very happy. (Don't panic about that 30MB allocation in the screenshot below - I'm working on it.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a `bool dirty` field inside the `Node` class. This is in addition to keeping a hash set. Then `MarkNodeClean()` doesn't need to remove nodes from the HashSet, shaving off some CPU cycles.

If you feel that adding a field inside `Node` class is too "dirty" (pun intended), then just make a `HashSet<(Node, bool)>` instead of `HashSet<Node>`, but you are loosing performance on allocating and garbage-collecting extra objects, which is not ideal since your code is performance-critical.

`UpdateDirtyNodes()` will take nodes one at a time until the HashSet is empty. After taking each node, it will look at the boolean flag to decide whether the node is actually dirty.

**P.S.**
You should remove `dirtyNodes.Clear();` from `UpdateDirtyNodes()`. This is a race condition. If a node is added after the while loop finds that dirtyNodes.Count is 0, then `dirtyNodes.Clear();` clears out that node without processing it. This is a separate bug, not related to your question.

Comment: I'm very confused by this answer. Are you suggesting that by adding a `dirty` flag to every node, `UpdateDirtyNodes` can then iterate over every node? Unfortunately this isn't easy, since the nodes are part of an octree and I don't have a single array with a reference to every node. I also believe that would result in poor performance when I could potentially have hundreds of thousands of nodes but only need to update a few hundred or a thousand. Or are you suggesting that when I mark a node clean I can just set the `dirty` flag to false? I guess that could work.

Comment: WRT to the bug, none of my code is threaded, so `dirtyNodes` cannot be changed between the time that the while loop checks that the count is 0 and the time that the array is cleared.

Comment: I should mention, your answer helped me to realise that `dirtyNodes.Clear()` was pointless and doing nothing, since the while loop could only exit if the list was already cleared.

Comment: Just saw your comments now. Glad I could help you come up with your own solution.